# number of entities always same as number of database tables?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In a conceptual model seem like each entity always correspond to one table in database. Is it possible to have three tables in database and not the same number of entities in conceptual model?

Comment: Probably because, as the faq states, this site is more dedicated to answering questions that involve code.  Your question is more of a how does something work, which is more of a programmers.stackexchange.com question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to have three tables in database and not the same number of entities in conceptual model?

Yes; Consider:

> [Person] -- [PersonToName] -- [Name]

Each person can have one or more Names, and each Name can belong to one or more Persons.

Entity Framework can take care of the Many-To-Many table and do:

> Person.Names (navigation property)
>
> Name.Persons (navigation property)

Additionally, when using Inheritance there is no need for the base table/entity so it gets rolled up into the derived table/entity.

Comment: The conceptual model is a object that does not have to map an object 1-to-1 to a table, which you stated.  EF will by default automatically when adding the 3 tables in the example to an EDMX(SSDL) will only create two objects (CSDL) Person and Name with navigational properties that map to the PersonToName/related table (in the SSDL/MSL).

Comment: OK, Sorry, I misunderstood your "Yes" :-) I (wrongly) assumed you meant that "yes, the number of tables is always the same as the number of entities".

Comment: The OP Title is the opposite of the OP summary question, so I quoted it for clarification. ;)